# NSMutableArray data not loading in tableView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I did XML parsing for the content I obtained from WCF Service. I loaded the data in `NSMutableArray` using `NSXMLParser`.Now I want that data to be loaded in tableview in a `UIView`. But I can see the empty tableview being loaded and data doesn't. Couldn't understand where I am going wrong.
My `NSMutableArray` is like this:

```
(
    {
   UserName="Roy";
   Password="126";
},
    {
    UserName="Joy";
   Password="123";
},
    {
    UserName="Rony";
   Password="5983";
}
-------------
-------------
)
```

And the code for UItableView is :

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

  NSMutableArray *arr;
  UITableView *tableView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UITableView* tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];    
}
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
    NSString *tempstring=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=  tempstring;
    return cell;

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
```

I am getting empty tableview with some empty rows. How can i fix this?

Comment: have you alloc the array

Comment: Yes I did it in load()  arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: Then try by setting breakpoints are your array getting initialize, does it carrying values. If yes, then check where it collapse.

Comment: Yeah, add breakpoint to numberOfRows to check that the array is what you think it is.  Stuff like that.

Comment: Yes it is getting initialised and Iam geting values.But couldn't c the breakpoint entering into TableView

Comment: No it is not entering into that section

Comment: if you are taking tableview programmatically then check for delegates have you set them.

Comment: I think "nduplessis" had posted correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you just add this code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegete:-

**EDITED**

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

 SMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

    UILabel *username = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 280, 30)];
    username.textColor =DARK_VIEW;
    username.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];      
    [username setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [username setText:[d valueForKey:@"UserName"]];
    [cell addSubview:username];
    [username release];

    UILabel *Password = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 25, 280, 30)];
    Password.textColor =DARK_VIEW;
    Password.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
    [Password setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

 [Password setText:[d valueForKey:@"Password"]];
  [cell addSubview:Password];
 [Password release];
return cell;

 }



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
  SMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
        NSString *forNExtViewString =[d valueForKey:@"EmployeID"];


  objSectonView =[[cntrSecodviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"cntrSecodviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSectonView animated:YES];



 }
```

Comment: But I want the whole data of array like this Roy 123 in one row and again Joy 123 in other row and Rony 5983 in other row .How can I do it?

Comment: check My edited answer and let me know if any query and if its useful dont forget accept answer and upwote ... :)

Comment: see its help full accepted answer but its in minus reputation.. lolz

Comment: Yes I have marked it as answer donno y it got - reputation.Hey I have a small question here if I try to add another UILabel then I am gettong error:Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCCESS" Here is my code for another UILabel.Im getting the value in NSMutableArray. UILabel *line=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 280,30)];
    line .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:10];        
    [line setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [line  setText:[d valueForKey:@"EmployeeId"]];
   [line addSubview:line ];   //error at this line //
   [line  release]; Please help

Comment: bcz u [line release] in comment so u got bad exc remove //

Comment: UILabel *line=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 280,10)];
    line .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:10];        
    [line setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [line  setText:[d valueForKey:@"EmployeeId"]];
   [line addSubview:line ];
   [line  release]; Eventhough Im getting error at this line  [line addSubview:line ];Can we add only 2 UILabels?

Comment: u addsubview in cell not in lable frnnd u do like [cell addSubview:line]; not like [line addSubview:line ];

Comment: Thanks Nitin.I was doing a silly mistake.I wish I can give u +100 if possible.Suppose if I want Employee Id value in that cell to be present but hidden can I do like this:line.hidden=YES; ?Because I have to pass that value to next view when that particular cell is clicked..

Comment: you using - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath for this particular task... see my edited Answer

Comment: Yes I am using (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the tableView delegate and datasource. Your datasource also looks like it contains a collection of NSDictionaries. In your cellForRow you have to correctly extract the values from the dictionary

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView* tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];    
}
```

Like Nitin Gohel pointed out

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
       cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserName"];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: yeah this is i am talking about.

Comment: But I want the whole data of array like this                                       Roy                                                                  123  in one row and again Joy 123 in other row and Rony 5983 in other row .How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing array at indexPath, and this array contain dictionary, so first get array and take it in dictionary and access it with `key` value

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this and confirm your delegates, that might be the reason of not getting tableview called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    tablView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 460)];
    tablView.delegate = self;
    tablView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tablView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                        (NSIndexPath*)indexPath

 {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tablView

                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]

                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

      UILabel *lbl5 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 5, 250, 50);];
      UILabel *lbl6 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 60, 250, 50)];

      lbl1.text = [arrayName objectAtIndex:i];
      lbl2.text = [arrayAddress objectAtIndex:i];

      NSString *tempstring=[arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSString *tempstring=[arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [cell addSubview:lbl1];
     [cell addSubview:lbl2];
     // cell.textLabel.text=  tempstring;
      return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hey I want the whole data in three rows each row seperated..But I am getting error :Program received signal SIGABRT at this line :cell.textLabel.text=  tempstring;

Comment: Tell have u started fetching the data.

Comment: No , but what I want is like this  Roy 123 in one row and again Joy 123 in other row and Rony 5983 in other row .How can I do it? I do not need separetly using valueforkey

Answer (score 0):

Your mutable array has elements of dictionary type. so while updating the text in table cell try to grab dictionary from array based on your indexPath.row and then objectForKey: for whichever key you want to use. see code below

you should try to use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[yourMutableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserName"]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[yourMutableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Password"];
```

and you can use the default separater of table cells.

Comment: Actually I want the whole array as it is with only three lines in a table i.e a separator between rows after Password

Comment: u want different sections, each sec containing one or two rows. right.

Comment: @arizah : you should try to use 

cell.textLabel.text = [[yourMutableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserName"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[yourMutableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Password"];

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure about the following things :

1. Values are retained in the array
2. Reload your TableView after the objects are added to array.

   i.e [tableView reloadData];

And Just replace your method with this one.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    //Over here just print the value of your array , to cross check whether the values are retained in the Array 
    NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    NSString *tempstring= [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"UserName"];
    cell.textLabel.text=  tempstring;
    return cell;

}
```

This would definitely bring the solution of your problem.